# Routing does not work well with HTML5-History-API

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, html5-history, html5mode

In a mean-stack web application, I use `html5mode` and have the following code in `index.html`:

```
<base href="/" />   
<script src="https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1/hosted/office.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/devote/HTML5-History-API/master/history.js"></script>
```

I have defined the following angular-ui-router:

```
    .state('addinHome', {
        url: '/addin/home',
        template: "home page"
    })
    .state('addinTest', {
        url: '/addin/test',
        template: '<a href="addin/home">one</a>',
        controller: 'TestCtrl'
    })
```

Then, I go to `https://localhost:3000/addin/test`, clicking on `one` leads me to `https://localhost:3000/addin/test#%2Faddin%2Fhome`, whereas I would want to go to `https://localhost:3000/addin/home`.

If I don't have `office.js` and `history.js`, clicking on `one` does lead me to `https://localhost:3000/addin/home`.

Does anyone know how to go to `https://localhost:3000/addin/home` while keeping `office.js` and `history.js`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it... just use

```
template: '<a href="addin/home" target="_self">one</a>'
```