# Make $location.path open in the same frame (target = "_self")

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, html5-history, location-href

In a mean-stack web application with html5mode, I have defined the following angular-ui-router

```
.state('addinHome', {
    url: '/addin/home',
    template: "home page"
})
```

Then, I have another page `https://localhost:3000/test/` with a button `<a href="/addin/home">button</a>`. Also in its controller, I have

```
... ...
$location.path("/addin/home")
... ...
```

Normally, both `$location.path` and the button lead to `https://localhost:3000/addin/home`.

Now, I add the following references in `index.html`:

```
<script src="https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1/hosted/office.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/devote/HTML5-History-API/master/history.js"></script>
```

It disturbs the ui-router. As a consequence, both `$location.path` and the button lead to `https://localhost:3000/test/#%2Faddin#%2Fhome`, which is NOT what I want.

I have found the solution to fix the button: it is using `<a href="addin/home" target="_self">button</a>` (opens the linked document in the same frame as it was clicked; see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44987738/702977)).

However, I have not found the solution to fix `$location.path("/addin/home")`. Could anyone help?

Comment: Wait, what's wrong with `$state.go('addinHome');`?

Comment: It leads to `https://localhost:3000/test/#%2Faddin#%2Fhome` like `$location.path`.

Comment: Why would you want `history.js` when router already manages history?

Comment: I have been using `html5mode`, [I need `history.js` to avoid `office.js` from totally disturbing html5mode.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44876806/702977).

Comment: And did you add `<base href="https://localhost:3000/" />` to the `<head>` of your html?

Comment: I always have `<base href="/" />` in my html. Changing it to `<base href="https://localhost:3000/" />` did not help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Inject `$window` as dependency.
- Try using `$window.open(URL,"_self")`

Comment: don't forget to inject `$window` as dependency.